# How to change project name in .project created from mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-eclipse-plugin

Here is the content of my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <name>SomeProject</name>

    <groupId>com.test.te</groupId>
    <artifactId>testjar</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
    ....
    ....
    </dependencies>
    <build>        
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am creating eclipse's .project file by executing the below command.

```
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Here is the content of my .project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>testjar</name>
    <comment>NO_M2ECLIPSE_SUPPORT: Project files created with the maven-eclipse-plugin are not supported in M2Eclipse.</comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

It is creating the project name testjar instead of SomeProject.

How to change it in maven way?

Comment: Why do you need to change that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added another plugin to support this, and gave project name

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <projectNameTemplate>SomeProject</projectNameTemplate>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Please note that the maven-eclipse-plugin is retired.