# Determine Eclipse Project Name from Maven pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, emf, ecore

I very much dislike IDE specific files in our code branches, so I want to get rid of all `.project`, `.classpath`, `.settings`, whatever files and folders.

I have several Eclipse Ecore Modelling Projects that are named differently in the Eclipse `.project` file than what is derived when they are imported as a Maven project. Which is a problem once Code needs the be generated from our models, because they refer to the name stated in `.project`.

The `groupId` and `artifactId` in the `pom.xml` are as follows:

```
<groupId>com.firm</groupId>
<artifactId>emf-model</artifactId>
```

So when importing them as a Maven Project, this one will be called `emf-model`.

However the model requires it to be called e.g. `com.firm.emf`.

I see some solutions to that (e.g. use `com.fire.emf` as an `artifactId`, rename the projects post import, change the model files to refer to the `artifactId`)

But I'd **really like a way to determine how the project will be called when it is imported as a Maven Project**. I'd also be very happy with a project name to be `groupId.artifactId` instead of just the `artifactId`.

Is there any Eclipse setting or Maven trick to do that?

Comment: You can set the project name in the `pom.xml` via the `maven-eclipse-plugin` plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410728/6505250

Comment: Please note that the Maven eclipse plugin is retired.

Comment: puh that might explain why I'm not getting it to do anything in eclipse photon..

Comment: So I gave up on this one. Still interested in the answer thou. Because I don't like my solution of using the full com.firm.emf string as artifactId.

Comment: The duplication of information between POM:s and `.project` files is most unfortunate. I don't know it that helps you at all, but I your are building with Tycho there is an option to use [POM-less builds](http://blog.vogella.com/2015/12/15/pom-less-tycho-builds-for-structured-environments/) to solve that problem.